# How to display main image when clicked on its thumbnail using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My DOM looks like this...

```
<div id="leftPan">
    <div id="leftmemberPan">
        <a href="#"><img src="/MyApp/images/${article.images[0].imageName}" alt="/MyApp/img/image_unavailable.jpg" class="testingMain"/></a>    
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnailPan">
        <c:forEach items="${article.images}" var="image">                       
            <a href="#"><img src="/MyApp/images/${image.imageName}" alt="/MyApp/img/image_unavailable.jpg" class="testing"/></a>                        
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

`leftmemberPan` is showing the main image and `thumbnailPan` is showing list of thumbnails

`<c:forEach items="${article.images}" var="image">` is just a JSTL tag which holds array of thumbnail images.

Please note that I am new to jQuery and using it for the fist time.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but it's not HTML. Please post the actual, rendered, HTML as seen by your browser; because that's what JavaScript works with.

Comment: he's using JSTL's forEach core tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a list of the main image src's within the alt tags of the thumbnails and then modify your leftmemberPan src to show the primary image.

Ex:

```
<img id="leftmemberPan" src="myplace_holder.jpg" />
<img class="thumbnail myimg.jpg" src="myimg_thumbnail.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".thumbnail").click(function()
    {
        var class_array = $(this).attr("class").split(' ');
        var newsrc = class_array[class_array.length-1]; // Pull new src from the class tag (assuming it's the last one)
        $("#leftmemberPan").attr('src', newsrc);
    });
</script>
```

Keep in mind this is just one way to do it.  You can store the primary image in many other ways as well.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Updated the code example to utilize the class attribute

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I am very new to jQuery; in fact using it for the fist time.

Comment: If I save list of the main image src's within alt tag, my page will not be able to show the alternate image/text when it is not able to find the thumbnail image. can you advice other method please?

Comment: That's very true, if you want you can store it in the class attribute =).  I updated my code sample to reflect this

Comment: The two answers below this also do work, however I try to avoid using custom attributes to avoid failing w3 standard validation.   See http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I'm pretty sure a class name with a `.` in it will confuse the heck out of a browsers css parser. Custom attributes are completely fine in an html validator, but if that's what you're worried about then throw it in the `rel` attribute tag not `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the path of your image into the data-path tag of each thumbnail, then when you click the thumb, grab that path from data-path and make the `src` of the main image that path.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Revising previous posts / answers (using jQuery 1.7) ...

```
<img class="thumbnail" data-file="myimg.jpg" src="myimg_thumbnail.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mainImage = $("img","#leftmemberPan")[0];
    $("#thumbnailPan").on("click", ".thumbnail", function(event){
        mainImage.src = $(this).data("file");
    });
</script>
```

- Use a data attribute for the main file image path.
- Do one (-time) DOM lookup after page load to reference the main image
  element.
- Just set the src attribute of the image element using the data attribute of the thumbnail.